# Richard Feynman is certainly not mischievous!

Tags: meaning, pejorative-language, figures-of-speech

In the introduction of [Richard Feynmans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Feynman) book [*Surely You're Joking, Mr. Feynman!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surely_You%27re_Joking,_Mr._Feynman!), a colleague describes Feynman's character.

The description makes sense to me - except for one word.
The word **mischievousness** is used.
That seems to describe a negative aspect of his character. But that meaning does not fit into the context in multiple ways:

Fo understand the meaning, I looked up synonyms of **mischievous** at merriam-webster.com. I add the synonyms found below, as this detail turned out to be central.

- The section is describing him in a somewhat neutral way, and this would be a single clearly negative item - with no further explanation.
- It would be unusual to have this negative statement about oneself in the introduction. Now, Feynman clearly is unusual... maybe there is an explanation later in the book. But then, the introduction is written by someone else, Albert R. Hibbs.
- Also, I do not see it as joking or so.

From the general context of what I know of Feynman, I am sure I would not see him as mischievous.

The word in context in the introduction, page 3, written by Albert R. Hibbs.:

> **Introduction**
>
> I hope these won't be the only memoirs of Richard Feynman. Certainly the reminiscences here
>   give a true picture of much of his character--his almost compulsive need to solve puzzles, his
>   **provocative mischievousness**, his indignant impatience with pretension and hypocrisy, and his
>   talent for one-upping anybody who tries to one-up him! This book is great reading: outrageous,
>   shocking, still warm and very human.
>
> For all that, it only skirts the keystone of his life: science. [...]

**To me, attributing "mischievousness" here to Richard Feynman makes no sense -**
**So, what am I missing here?**

Excerpt of http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/mischievous:

> - Synonyms MISCHIEVOUS
>
>   - 1 tending to or exhibiting reckless playfulness
>
>     Synonyms arch, devilish, elvish, espiègle, impish, knavish, leprechaunish, pixie (also pixy), pixieish, prankish, puckish,
>       rascally, roguish, scampish, sly, tricksy, waggish, wicked
>   - 2 engaging in or marked by childish misbehavior
>
>     Synonyms bad, contrary, errant, froward, misbehaving, mischievous
>   - 3 causing or capable of causing harm
>
>     Synonyms adverse, bad, baleful, baneful, damaging, dangerous, deleterious, detrimental, evil, hurtful, ill, injurious, mischievous,
>       nocuous, noxious, pernicious, prejudicial, wicked

Note that http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/mischievousness turns up less negative synonyms.

Comment: This question is completely based on the assumption that "that seems to describe a negative aspect of his character ". This assumption is wrong — most people see this as a positive trait (mischievousness coming close in meaning to "playfulness").

Comment: You're missing the fact that several dictionaries list the definitions of *mischievous* in an order which makes it seem that it inevitably had negative connotations.  Compare, eg, the inconsistent Merriam-Webster definitions of [*mischievous*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mischievous) and [*mischievousness*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/mischievousness).

Comment: @oerkelens I derive that assumption from the text, say that it can not be right, and ask where I went wrong. How comes that "most people see this as a positive trait" when the word is synonym to mostly negative things - plus a few of the playfulness-related.

Comment: @HotLicks looking at synonyms mischievous and mischievousness of www.merriam-webster.com seems to reveal the actual problem: I looked at http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/mischievous, which is much more negative in terms of synonyms than http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/mischievousness. So your comment is the actual answer!

Comment: If the reason that I found a negative meaning, not a positive, was only that I looked up mischievous instead of mischievousness, this question is indeed not useful, but causes uselessconfusion. I'd like to delete it if anybody agrees? (but it's worth adding a questioin about why mischievous and mischievousness differ so much - which is the core of all this)

Comment: @HotLicks So, in looking at the title, can we say that "Richard Feynman is ceartainly not mischievous, while he does show mischievousness!"?

Comment: Meaning isn't prescribed by a dictionary entry; that is, the dictionary isn't giving absolutely every nuance that could eventually be used, it isn't telling you that you must use a word in the stated way. Even if the canonical term 'mischief' is negative, say when applied to a 10 year old who accidentally burns down an abandoned barn, for someone like Feynman, it can probably be taken to mean that Feynman isn't as serious as you'd expect some ivory tower professor.

Comment: @Mitch Yes, I agree with all this - and I can easily read the text this way - except at this single location, where I cound not get it match in any way. But as it turns out, it is because I translated  "mischievous", instead of "mischievousness", which have a dramatically different definition in websters, at least. HotLicks found that - but maybe I shoulld make that an answer myself?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel You're making too much out of this. There's barely any difference between mischievous and mischievousness (if any beyond the suffix). In this context, mischievous and mischievousness are to be taken as the answers explain. They could still be understood as negative. Calling him mischievous could be a euphemism  (weakening) of calling him kind of a jerk. Feynman is not a god, not everything about him must be perfect.

Comment: Understand that there's no difference in the meaning of "mischievousness" and "the attribute of being mischievous".  The reason for the difference in Merriam-Webster is most likely that the two definitions were written by different people at different times.  (And keep in mind that lexicographers, as a rule, have no sense of humor.)

Answer (score 4):

From what I know of Feynman (I've read that book and others) it sounds like an apt description. **Mischievous** has a secondary sense of *impishly playful*, which I believe the quote intends. [One source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mischievous) has:

> roguishly or slyly teasing, as a glance

...while [another](http://www.yourdictionary.com/mischievous) has:

> prankish; teasing; full of tricks

Answer (score 2):

Mischievous is not a negative attribute. Provocatively mischievous implies that his mischief is provoking others (maybe to think more rigorously). Obv. the line surely... itself was a response to his mischief :)

Comment: That would make it all cllear, of course. But I'm still wondering why I seemed to find almost only negative synonyms - with reading it as  "impish:, it makes perfect sense. But how to tell it's not negative if most synonyms are clearly negative? I'll list some in the question to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 2):

Mischievousness can also be used if a "bad" action is undertaken while doing it for a "well intended" reason.

> *Father eating chocolate. Son approaches, clearly after chocolate.*
>   **Father:** "Do not touch my dessert!"
>   *Son literally touches the chocolates, to jokingly defy his father. Never actually takes anything from the plate. He just smiles because he proved a point.*

That'd also fall under the general description of mischievousness. It's willfully going against the rules more or less to prove a point or make a joke.

Richard Feynman very famously questioned things that others seemed to have made their minds up about. He'd create a minor disturbance, that simply led people to reevaluate their opinion (that had previously been set in stone).

His intent was not to create chaos, he did it with his heart in the right place. So mischievousness seems like an apt description for this behaviour.